# Wanted to delete ldap node and delete all the subtree node under it

Tags: java, apache, ldap, jndi, spring-ldap

I wanted to delete ldap node and delete all the subtree node under it.
eg.I want to delete ou=F115630019  along with its child node i.e cn =xxxxx and ou=115630019 showed in snap shot.

[image]

While running the below code i am encountering below error.Please let me know how can i fix this problem.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
    at deleteorg.deleteDN(deleteorg.java:28)
    at deleteorg.deleteDN(deleteorg.java:58)
    at deleteorg.main(deleteorg.java:96)
```

java code:-

```
  import java.util.*;
    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.naming.ContextNotEmptyException;
    import javax.naming.NameNotFoundException;
    import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
    import javax.naming.NamingException;
    import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
    import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttributes;
    import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
    import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
    import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
    import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

    public class deleteorg {

        public boolean deleteDN(String srchost, String srcport, String srcuserId,String srcpasswd, String srcBaseDn, String deleteDn) {
            String attribList = "";
            String temp = null;
            try {
                DirContext srcCtx = createContext(srchost, srcport, srcBaseDn,
                        srcuserId, srcpasswd);

                SearchControls srcont = new SearchControls();
                srcont.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
                int i = deleteDn.indexOf(",");
                System.out.println("i: "+i);
                System.out.println("deleteDN="+deleteDn);
                deleteDn = deleteDn.substring(0,deleteDn.indexOf(","));
                System.out.println("index->>"+i+"------" + deleteDn);

                NamingEnumeration answer = null;
                try {
                 answer = srcCtx.search(deleteDn, "objectclass=*", srcont);
                 System.out.println("Answer"+ answer);
                } catch (NameNotFoundException ne) {
                    System.out.println("name not found exception");
                }
                if (answer != null) {
                    while (answer.hasMore()) {
                        Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes(true);
                        System.out.println("Attr"+ attrs);
                        SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();
                        System.out.println("Search Result"+sr);
                        String addDN = sr.getName() + "," + deleteDn;
                        System.out.println("adDN"+addDN);
                        String attribnamevalues = "";
                        if (addDN.indexOf(',') == 0)
                            addDN = addDN.substring(1); // get rid of the leading
                                                        // ","

                        try {
                            System.out.println("AddDN"+addDN);
                            srcCtx.destroySubcontext(addDN);
                    System.out.println("destroyed");
                        } catch (ContextNotEmptyException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    deleteDN(srchost, srcport, srcuserId, srcpasswd, srcBaseDn,
                            deleteDn);
                }
                srcCtx.close();
                return true;
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        public DirContext createContext(String servername, String port, String basedn, String username, String password) {
            System.out.println("sername=" + servername + "#port=" + port + "#baseDn="+ basedn + "#uid=" + username + "#pwd=" + password);

            DirContext ctx;
            Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://" + servername + ":" + port + "/"
                    + basedn);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

            try {
                ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
                return (ctx);

            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return (null);
            }
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            deleteorg ctx = new deleteorg();

            ctx.deleteDN("localhost", "1389","cn=Directory Manager","Welcome1","ou=organizations,dc=xyz,dc=com","ou=F115630019  ,ou=organizations,dc=xyz,dc=com");


        }

    }
```

Comment: See whether your LDAP server supports the [tree delete control](https://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/ldap-subtree-delete-control/).

Answer (score -1):

Only leaf nodes can be deleted from ldap. You need to follow these steps.

1. Traverses the subtre, find the last element
2. Deletes this node in the reverse order and move up till you reach the target/highlighted node